# Why kernels make use of the high logical address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, windows-kernel

For 32bit OS. linux kernel occupies the high logical address 3~4GB (and 2~4GB for windows).
  I wonder why the designer choose the high address, instead of 0~1GB for linux, and because the kernel is actually in the phiscal low address, the choice of low logical address will lead to a more harmonious logical/physical relationship. why not?

Comment: Related: [What's the advantage of the 3G/1G VM split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712863/whats-the-advantage-of-3g-1g-vm-split-32bit-linux-kernel)

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I did know the advantages of 3G/1G split, but why not 1G/3G, the question doesn;'t answered it

Comment: @sawdust I cannot understand the advantage that user programs able to occupy the low address from ZERO. on the one hand it make little difference with from ONE Giga (as a C/C++ programer, I never concern about where my program will be located), one the other hand, actually, gcc/g++ links the program not from 0 as default, I found this by `objdump -h /bin/ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before PIC (Position-independent code) was popular, there are lots of static linked programs can only be loaded at specified address, likely [0x400000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14314021/why-linux-gnu-linker-chose-address-0x400000)

To be able to compatible with these programs, the kernel must not obtain the address space. So the kernel is located at high 1G address space.